# adding another post method to nodejs

Tags: node.js

i have the following code in server.js

```
app.route('/push')
    .get(pushApis.list_all_tasks)
    .post(pushApis.send_notification);
```

and included js has:

```
exports.send_notification = function(req, res) {
console.log("start of send_notification ");
console.log('req.method:' + req.method);
 if (req.method == 'POST') {
    var jsonString = '';

}
```

if i have to add another post method then how do i do it? adding a new method to the server.js does not seems to the right approach as during the call i am not specifying the method name send_notification

Comment: Hello it's me again. Are you trying to make a post request handler which saves some data to the database?

Comment: well i need to different type of posts

Comment: You said that you are "not specifying the method name"? Could you tell me how you do that?